# JSON.parse generates error with backslash

Tags: php, jquery, json

Why does the following JSON fail to be parsed by `JSON.parse`?

```
{"page_title":"contact us","val":{"pattern":"/email/\s+us\s*(.*?)/\s/","type":"1"}}
```

When I log `result` to the console then it gives above output. After using `JSON.parse` it gives this error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 1649 at JSON.parse ()
>   see my code below:

```
var result ='<?php echo json_encode($output);?>';
console.log(result);
var data = JSON.parse(result);
```

Comment: The code you've shown in the question works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/epq87nhg/

Comment: var a = '{"page_title":"contact us","val":{"pattern":"/email/\s+us\s*(.*?)/\s","type":"1"}}';
var data = JSON.parse(a);
console.log(data);

Comment: `json_decode(str_replace('\\',"\\\\", $json), true);` would do the magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use addslashes function because you are using regex into string

```
var result ='<?php echo addslashes(json_encode($output));?>';
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple... don't single-quote wrap your json object nor call `JSON.parse()`.**

```
let result = <?php echo json_encode($output); ?>;
```

Now `result` is a javascript object that is ready to use.

If you are `json_encode()` properly, your string will look like this:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NtjWh))

```
$array = [
    "page_title" => "contact us",
    "val" => [
        "pattern" => "/email/\s+us\s*(.*?)/\s/",
        "type" => "1"
    ]
];

echo json_encode($array);
```

Output:

```
{"page_title":"contact us","val":{"pattern":"\/email\/\\s+us\\s*(.*?)\/\\s\/","type":"1"}}
```

p.s. your regex pattern looks questionable with those unescaped slash after email and after the capture group despite the pattern having slashes as delimiters.

If this pattern is for js execution, you might have better success with:

```
email\/\s+us\s*(.*?)\/\s
```

without delimters so that your pattern can be used by a regex function as a variable.

**And if my above logic doesn't scream loud enough, here is a javascript demo that shows that `json_encode()` does not need `addslashes()`:**

The below `data` variable will be populated by:

```
data = <?php echo json_encode([
                      "page_title" => "contact us",
                      "val" => [
                      "pattern" => "email\/\s+us\s*(.*?)\/\s",
                      "type" => "1"
                  ]
                  ]); ?>;
```

```js
let data = {"page_title":"contact us","val":{"pattern":"email\\\/\\s+us\\s*(.*?)\\\/\\s","type":"1"}},
    str = "You can email/ us all-day-long if you wish/  or not.";

console.log(data.page_title);
console.log(data.val.pattern);
regex = new RegExp(data.val.pattern,"g");
console.log(str.match(regex));
console.log(data.val.type);
```

Comment: __"i don't know why people mark as negative without any knowledge?"__  ... @Martin the reason that the other answer was downvoted is probably because it doesn't fix your initial problem of single-quote-wrapping your json string.  Please read my answer carefully.  You **do not need to mutate your json string with `addslashes()`**.  By accepting a workaround instead of a clean direct solution, you are contributing to the misinformation of future researchers.  There is absolutely no advantage to other answer when json_encode alone is perfectly qualified for this task.